# Using AngularJS $filter('filter') with OR

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have this Object

```
$scope.items = [
    {id:1, name:'John'},
    {id:2, name:'Steve'},
    {id:3, name:'Joey'},
    {id:4, name:'Mary'},
    {id:5, name:'Marylin'}];
```

I need to filter by two value like 3, 4 I'm trying something like that

```
$scope.items2 =  $filter('filter')($scope.items, {id:3,4});
```

How can i do that? need to use custom Filter?

http://jsfiddle.net/cWVrV/23/

Answer (score 5):

Use callback function:

```
$scope.items2 =  $filter('filter')($scope.items, function(obj) {
    return obj.id == 3 || obj.id == 4;
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cWVrV/24/

Or simply use plain old [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the same way :

```
$scope.items2 = $scope.items.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.id == 3 || obj.id == 4;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there any way to compare this values with an array like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cWVrV/26/

Comment: @PedroMarques [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: @Blackhole Can you make a example in fiddle? I try many ways like return obj.indexOf($scope.val); but don't work